# explode string on multiple words

Tags: php, arrays, regex, explode

There is a string like this:

```
$string = 'connector:rtp-monthly direction:outbound message:error writing data: xxxx yyyy zzzz date:2015-11-02 10:20:30';
```

This string is from user Input. So it will never have the same order. It's an input field which I need to split to build a DB query.

Now I would like to split the string based on words given in a array() which is like a mapper containing the words I need to find in the string. Looking like so:

```
$mapper = array(
    'connector' => array('type' => 'string'),
    'direction' => array('type' => 'string'),
    'message' => array('type' => 'string'),
    'date' => array('type' => 'date'),
);
```

Only the keys of the `$mapper` will be relevant. I've tried with foreach and explode like:

```
 $parts = explode(':', $string);
```

But the problem is: There can be colons somewhere in the string so I don't need to explode there. I only need to explode if a colon is followed right after the mapper key. The mapper keys in this case are:

```
connector    // in this case split if "connector:" is found
direction    // untill "direction:" is found
message      // untill "message:" is found
date         // untill "date:" is found
```

But remember also, the user input can varey. So the string will always change ant the order of the string and the `mapper array()` will never be in the same order. So I'm not sure if explode is the right way to go, or if I should use a regex. And if so how to do it.

The desired result should be an array looking something like this:

```
$desired_result = array(
    'connector' => 'rtp-monthly',
    'direction' => 'outbound',
    'message' => 'error writing data: xxxx yyyy zzzz',
    'date' => '2015-11-02 10:20:30',
);
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: split by space and by `:` after

Comment: it may be done with a regexp, any chance you could change that string to some easier to parse format (eg. json, etc) ?

Comment: @Calimero if json will help I'm open for solutions with json

Comment: `$result = array_column(array_map(function($v){return explode(":", $v);}, explode(" ", $string)), 1, 0);`

Comment: `/([^:\s]+):(\S+)/` Two capture groups, one before the colon, one afterwards.  Use `preg_match_all()` in addition. Is `writing` and `data` to be ignored?

Comment: it might help because your string format is basically a key-value list, with some values having unenclosed multiple word strings (thus making the space a bad choice for field delimiter). Json is the first idea that pops to mind, php having native functions json_encode() and json_decode() to assist, other data formats might do nicely too.

Comment: @Blag updated the question. Now you will see that splitting by `space and :` will not work

Comment: @Calimero could you please create a sort of example with the json?

Comment: sure, there you go : `$string = '{"connector":"rtp-monthly","direction":"outbound","message":"error writing data: xxxx yyyy zzzz","date":"2015-11-02 10:20:30"}'; $desired_result = json_decode($string, true);`

Comment: haha thank you @Calimero ok, right, that's what I'm trying to get. the string is from user input...

Comment: meaning you don't have control over the format... well that's too bad, considering all the answers below involve a lot more work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trickier part of this is matching the original string. You can do it with Regex with the help of [lookahead positive assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$pattern = "/(connector|direction|message|date):(.+?)(?= connector:| direction:| message:| date:|$)/";
$subject = 'connector:rtp-monthly direction:outbound message:error writing data: xxxx yyyy zzzz date:2015-11-02 10:20:30';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

$returnArray = array();
foreach($matches as $item)
{
    $returnArray[$item[1]] = $item[2];
}
```

In this Regex `/(connector|direction|message|date):(.+?)(?= connector:| direction:| message:| date:|$)/`, you're matching:

- `(connector|direction|message|date)` - find a keyword and capture it;
- `:` - followed by a colon;
- `(.+?)` - followed by any character many times non greedy, and capture it;
- `(?= connector:| direction:| message:| date:|$)` - up until the next keyword or the end of the string, using a non-capturing look-ahead positive assertion.

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [connector] => rtp-monthly
    [direction] => outbound
    [message] => error writing data: xxxx yyyy zzzz
    [date] => 2015-11-02 10:20:30
)
```

I didn't use the mapper array just to make the example clear, but you could use `implode` to put the keywords together.

Comment: how could I insert the keys of `$mapper = array()` in the `$pattern`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's the purpose of this `$mapper` array. It would help if you could edit your question and clarify what's the intended behavior. Also, your updated string breaks this regex, since you are using a delimiter (the colon) as part of the data as well (the time part). If possible, I strongly suggest you change the input format, to something like JSON for instance.

Comment: question is updated, makes more sense now. I know, the delimiter, that's part of my problem.. Thats why I would like to use those "mapping words" in front of delimiter. Or a combination of delimitor with those mapping words...

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think it achieves what you need now.

Answer (score 0):

Our aim isto make one array that contains the values of two arrays that we would extract from the string. It is neccesary to have two arrays since there are two string delimeters we wish to consider.
Try this:

```
$parts = array();
$large_parts = explode(" ", $string);

for($i=0; $i<count($large_parts); $i++){
    $small_parts = explode(":", $large_parts[$i]);
    $parts[$small_parts[0]] = $small_parts[1];
}
```

`$parts` should now contain the desired array

Hope you get sorted out.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @TroubleZero thank you for your answer. This wil not really help me. Consider I could get a string containing a date value like `date:2015-11-02 08:10:15` so I really need and want to split on that explained mapping array keys ...

Comment: For the date part, you could first work on replacing the ':' with "-" or "/" to avoid confusing formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a regular expression and `explode()`. Consider the following code:

```
$str = "connector:rtp-monthly direction:outbound message:error writing data date:2015-11-02";
$regex = "/([^:\s]+):(\S+)/i";
// first group: match any character except ':' and whitespaces
// delimiter: ':'
// second group: match any character which is not a whitespace
// will not match writing and data
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
$mapper = array();
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $match);
    $mapper[$key][] = $value;
}
```

Additionally, you might want to think of a better way to store the strings in the first place (JSON? XML?).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. The regex is there to "catch" the key (any sequence of characters, excluding blank space and ":"). Starting from there, I use "explode" to "recursively" split the string. Tested ad works good

```
$string = 'connector:rtp-monthly direction:outbound message:error writing data date:2015-11-02';

$element = "(.*?):";
preg_match_all( "/([^\s:]*?):/", $string, $matches);
$result = array();
$keys = array();
$values = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach( $matches[0] as $id => $match ) {
    $exploded = explode( $matches[ 0 ][ $id ], $string );
    $keys[ $counter ] = $matches[ 1 ][ $id ];
    if( $counter > 0 ) {
        $values[ $counter - 1 ] = $exploded[ 0 ];
    }
    $string = $exploded[ 1 ];
    $counter++;
}
$values[] = $string;
$result = array();
foreach( $keys as $id => $key ) {
    $result[ $key ] = $values[ $id ];
}
print_r( $result );
```

Comment: Thank you! Please see updated string in question: `$string = 'connector:rtp-monthly direction:outbound message:error writing data: xxxx date:2015-11-02 10:20:30';` I think I really need to split on that given `mapper array()`

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_split() to explode() by multiple delimiters in PHP

Just a quick note here. To explode()  a string using multiple delimiters in PHP you will have to make use of the regular expressions. Use pipe character to separate your delimiters.

```
$string = 'connector:rtp-monthly direction:outbound message:error writing data: xxxx yyyy zzzz date:2015-11-02 10:20:30';
$chunks = preg_split('/(connector|direction|message)/',$string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Print_r to check response output.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($chunks);
echo '</pre>';
```

PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY  – To return only non-empty pieces.